# C++ Mongodb driver, not working

Tags: c++, mongodb, qt, exception, driver

I'am having problems using c++ mongo db driver. I downloaded the "legacy" branch and built it myself dynamically with /MD switch, using vc12.0.
I'am trying to connect to my database and retrieve some fields from the collection, but getting the weird exception. I'm using QT 5.4, The code is:

```
auto status = mongo::client::initialize();
std::string errmsg;
if(status.isOK())
{
try
{
    mongo::HostAndPort serv("127.0.0.1:27017");

    c.connect(serv,errmsg);
}
catch( const mongo::DBException &e ) {
    QString qstr(e.what());
    qDebug() << "caught " << qstr;
  }

mongo::Query query = mongo::Query("{'name':''}");
auto test = c.findOne("database.clients",query);
}
```

On the findone line I get the exception: 
[image: Errors]http://rghost.ru/7PsTG9Sxc/image.png

What is the right way to execute find/findone queries in c++ driver? 
And, please give me work samples for another mongo driver functions, how properly run it on c++.

**UPDATE**

Stack Trace Screenshot of the exception:
[image]

I guees it is some problem with std::string?

**UPDATE 2**

Ok, i made a RELEASE build in qt creator, and mongo driver works fine with my programm release build. It seems that my program /MDd conflicts with /MD mongodriver. However, i wanted to compile mongodb driver with /MDd so i can use debugger, but! When i build the driver with dbg=on, i get only one library: libmongoclient-gd.lib. No dlls, no "lubmongoclient" debug built, like whats with this driver? Is it even possible to build it with /MDd

Comment: Have you called mongo::client::initialize?

Comment: Yes, of course. Added to code block.

Comment: Is there a way you could provide a text stack trace? It is hard to see from an image what the function names and line numbers are.

Comment: @acm i added the screenshot in my main post

Comment: You need to be very careful on Windows to ensure that all DLLs are using the same runtime library. Is Qt and also your application also built with the /MD switch?

Comment: @acm Please look at my main post, i updated it

Comment: @acm i'm having weird incoincompatibility issues with this mongo driver

Comment: Did you read these parts of the documentation
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Download-and-Compile-the-Legacy-Driver#building-multiple-windows-library-variants
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Download-and-Compile-the-Legacy-Driver#windows-autolinking

Comment: @acm yes, i have all the includepaths and libpath set in qt. The problem is  `Depending on how you built the driver, you may end up with a static library, a dynamic library, or both. On Windows, you may end up with many libraries with different names.`

Comment: @acm If i try and build the driver with /MDd or statically, i get only one library, libmongoclient or libmongoclient-gd. When i try to link for example the `libmongoclient-gd` whis is produced by compiling the driver with `dbg=non` i got linker error, that `libmongoclient not found`. It just not getting build, i searched the prefix folder and main folder with sources, no other libs getting built using non default configuration.

Comment: What, excatly, do you mean by build the driver with /MDd. That should be being done automatically by the build system when doing a debug build against the dynamic runtime. Did you actually read the section on producing multiple variants on windows?

Comment: In particular, you should be building the driver four times:

`scons $ARGS install`
`scons $ARGS install --dbg=on`
`scons $ARGS install --dynamic-windows --sharedclient`
`scons $ARGS install --dynamic-windows --sharedclient --dbg=on`

Comment: Also, please note that on Windows you shouldn't need to specify libmongoclient explicitly as a link library - it should be found automatically via autolib linking.

Comment: Were you able to get it built with the variants that you expected?